How to calculate number of trainable parameters in CNN model with depth-wise separable and attention layers?
I have a CNN model contain depth-wise separable layers and soft based attention layers. I know how calculate numbers of parameters in standard convolutional layer but I can't calculate the parameters of each of:

separable_conv2d_6 layer
separable_conv2d_7 layer
soft_attention layer

Hint
_______________________________________________________________________________
Filter size in separable_conv2d_6, separable_conv2d_7 and soft attention  = 3X3
_______________________________________________________________________________

Thanks in advance.
